# How to update a list item's Workflow Status field?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I have created an Approval field for my list programmatically:

```
var fieldName = mylist.Fields.Add("Approval", SPFieldType.WorkflowStatus, false)
```

[see this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldworkflowstatus.init(v=office.14).aspx)

Now I want to add list item programmatically and update this field with code, but I am stuck here. To update a link field I can use `SPFieldUrlValue`, but I cannot find `SPFieldWorkflowStatusValue` to update my field, how can I achieve this?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All the statuses are stored as a integer, below are the codes I have come across and tested so far:

• NotStarted = 0

• FailedOnStart = 1

• InProgress = 2

• ErrorOccurred = 3

• StoppedByUser = 4

• Completed = 5

• FailedOnStartRetrying = 6

• ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7

• ViewQueryOverflow = 8

• Canceled = 15

• Approved = 16

• Rejected = 17

[Source](http://geekswithblogs.net/simonh/archive/2013/04/12/sharepoint-2010-workflow-status-values.aspx)

Comment: And since he is using c# he can use the SPWorkflowStatus enum http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx